# how to use extract_links() to get url from a webpage encoding by 'gb2312'

Tags: python, scrapy, codec

enviroment: python 2.7  os: ubuntu

I want to extract some link form a webpage,and i test it in scrapy shell
but i encounter UnicodeError:

my code:

```
le = LinkExtractor()

le.extract_links(response)
```

error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position
>   39: invalid continuation byte

in this webpage souce code ,i find it is encoding 'gb2312',so i try to:

print response.body.decode('gb2312')    it can print all html

but when:

```
le.extract_links(response.body.decode('gb2312')),
```

have error:

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'text'

because the extract_links need htmlresponse as argument,but response.body  response.text return 'byte' and 'Unicode' obeject;

type(response)

result : class 'scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse'

so i don't know how to fix response,and extract links from it;
Is there any way to specify that the response returned is 'utf-8' instead of 'gb2312'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/linkextractors/lxmlhtml.py", line 128, in extract_links
    links = self._extract_links(doc, response.url, response.encoding, base_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/linkextractors/__init__.py", line 109, in _extract_links
    return self.link_extractor._extract_links(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/linkextractors/lxmlhtml.py", line 76, in _extract_links
    return self._deduplicate_if_needed(links)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/linkextractors/lxmlhtml.py", line 91, in _deduplicate_if_needed
    return unique_list(links, key=self.link_key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 78, in unique
    seenkey = key(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/linkextractors/lxmlhtml.py", line 43, in <lambda>
    keep_fragments=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/w3lib/url.py", line 433, in canonicalize_url
    parse_url(url), encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/w3lib/url.py", line 510, in parse_url
    return urlparse(to_unicode(url, encoding))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/w3lib/util.py", line 27, in to_unicode
    return text.decode(encoding, errors)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 39: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to specify encoding manually like this:
`response.replace(encoding='gb2312')` and then try to pass that to the link extractor.

Edit: So it seems scrapy fails to specify url encoding somewhere down the link processing chain (at `w3lib.url.canonicalize_url` I believe when performing deduplication). As a workaround you can use this:

```
resp = response.replace(encoding='utf8', body=response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: thanks..i try to le.extract_links(response.replace(encoding='gb2312')),but it have same problem,and i test it in scrapy shell

Comment: @crydby, that's weird, can you provide a url on which this happens and maybe a full traceback that precedes the `UnicodeDecodeError`?

Comment: ,thanks,full traceback that precedes the UnicodeDecodeErroe  have post above.

Comment: it works,thanks,and i think i should learn more about request and htmlresponse.

Answer (score 0):

w3lib.url.canonicalize_url works incorrectly in this webpage , and the above workaround that

`resp = response.replace(encoding='utf8', body=response.text.encode('utf8'))`

only work in scrapy shell

so we can  specify the canonicalize=True in spider

like this:

```
LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True)
```

but in scrapy documents said,under normal circumstances,

> you’re using LinkExtractor to follow links it is more robust to keep
>   the default canonicalize=False